# MySQL 2 Tables, query before insert

Tags: mysql

I'm perplexed, here is what I have.

Two tables, one is temporary, one is permanent.

```
 table  Temptable:   
 city , state          //- has a list of 20 citys and states

 table  Permtable: 
  city , state          //- has hundreds of citys and states
```

I want to do two things:

1. I want to use city and state from Temptable and query the Permtable to see if it already contains
   that city and state.  If it doesn't I want it to add it.
2. IF it has a match in city and state, I want it to play c:\sound.wav and then I want it add it to the

permtable.

I am lost as to how to do this.

Comment: I am not following part #2.  If the match already exists between the permanent table and teh temp table, why do you need to "add it to the permanent table?  The way you question reads is that you always want to add the record from the temp table to the perm table, but you only want to play a sound if the added record already existed in the permanent table.  Is this correct?

Comment: If it exists, I want to add it, I want it to let me know.

If it doesn't match, I just want it to add it.

I know it sounds odd, but that's what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will tell you which records exist or don't exist from your TempTable:

```
SELECT T.City, T.State, CASE WHEN P.State IS NULL THEN 'DOES NOT EXIST' ELSE 'DOES EXIST' END
FROM TempTable T
   LEFT JOIN PermTable P ON T.City = P.City AND T.STate = P.State
```

You can INSERT those records that don't exists in the PermTable like such:

```
INSERT INTO PermTable
SELECT T.City, T.State
FROM TempTable T
   LEFT JOIN PermTable P ON T.City = P.City AND T.STate = P.State
WHERE P.State IS NULL
```

Not sure about your requirement to play a sound and it doesn't make sense to then add it (since it already exists).

Comment: No need for a sound really, I actually, in the future, want it to send me an email and let me know that it found the match.

Comment: I changed things a bit, but can't get it to work:

SELECT T.FirstName, CASE WHEN P.FirstName IS NULL THEN 'DOES NOT EXIST' ELSE 'DOES EXIST' END
FROM employee T
   LEFT JOIN Persons P ON T.FirstName = P.FirstName AND T.LastName = P.LastName

It comes back with two rows, and on each says Does not exist.  But, the FirstName and LastName both exist in a single row.

Comment: @MRTim2day -- I'd be happy to help but it seems to work for me with your query.  Here, I built you a Fiddle for testing: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bc435/2

Comment: Very cool, never seen that before.  Obviously, you're right.  I need to figure out what I messed up on.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @MRTim2day -- No problem!  Glad I could help, probably a data issue.  Best of luck.

Comment: Ok, so I figured out my error.  I have the first code working and I get exists on one and doesnt exist on the 2nd.  Both are correct now.

So, the 2nd part of the code above, how do I add that to the top code?

Comment: @MRTim2day -- this should help get you going in the right direction: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3cfd7/1 -- I'm probably logging off shortly, but will check back tomorrow :-)

Answer (score 0):

Since we have no code to run with here, query temptable for city and state, then query SELECT COUNT(id) FROM permtable WHERE city='$tempcity' AND state='$tempstate'.

Then user mysqli_num_rows on your query to see if any matches were found.

```
$q= "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM temptable WHERE city='$tempcity' AND state='$tempstate'";
$r = @mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

if(mysqli_num_rows($r) != 0) {
echo "<embed src =\"sound.wav\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\"></embed>";
}
else { 
//Do your other stuff.
}
```

It really depends on how you have your table set up. If you have column 'State' and column 'City' where 'City' is something like 'Dallas-Austin-Houstin-San Antonio' then you will have to query for 'State', explode the value of 'City' into an array, run a while to check for $tempcity in the array, which would look like the following:

```
$q = "SELECT city FROM permtable WHERE state='$tempstate'";
$r = @mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

if (mysqli_num_rows($r) == 1) { //STATE MATCH

$cityCheck = explode("-", $row['city']);
$i = 0;
$count = count($cityCheck);
$goodMatch = 0;

while ($i < $count) { //find out if user already voted on post
if ($cityCheck[$i] == $tempcity) { 
$goodMatch = 1;
} //City State match
else { } //City does not match with state, continue while loop.
$i++;
} //END WHILE

else { } //STATE DID NOT MATCH

if ($goodmatch) {
echo "<embed src =\"sound.wav\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\"></embed>";
}
else {}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help so far, I appreciate it.  New to MySQL so struggling is putting it lightly.

Both tables have separate row for each city and state so there is 1 city 1 state for each row.

Comment: I just assumed you were using PHP along with MySQL since you were talking about how you wanted to play a sound. Is this correct? If so, follow my first code block since your cities are not stored exclusively to each state. If you have anymore questions I will hang around.

Comment: Not using any PHP, this is just with MySQL query in Sqlyog.  I guess that's why I can't get it to work :-)

The sound will end up being an alert, something that sends an email eventually.  Sorry I was confusing there.

My cities and states are matched on each row.  So row 1 has Albany and New York.  2nd row has Asheville and North Carolina, etc.

Does that make more sense?

Comment: Oh, ok. Whoops. Sgeddes answer is what you're looking for then. If MySQL can play sounds then I definitely have a lot left to learn.

Comment: Hehe, yea I don't think it can play sounds but that's OK.  Thanks for your help tonight.